# Doubts regarding a variable scope with declaration variable via let

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6

I've run into the strange assertion in a book in my point of view. I guess that I don't understand something but anyway it will be great if you shed light on the situation.

```
ajax('<host1>/items',                                       
   items => {
   for (let item of items) {
      ajax(`<host2>/items/${item.getId()}/info`,            
      dataInfo => {
        ajax(`<host3>/files/${dataInfo.files}`,            
           processFiles);
   });
  }
});
```

An author pay attention on :

> There’s another hidden problem with this code. Can you guess what it is? It occurs when you mix a synchronous artifact like a for..of imperative block invoking asynchronous functions. Loops aren’t aware that there’s latency in those calls, so they’ll always march ahead no matter what, which can cause some really unpredictable and hard-to-diagnose bugs. In these situations, you can improve matters by creating closures around your asynchronous functions, managed by using forEach() instead of the loop.

Instead of it they offer the following:

```
ajax('/data',                            
  items  => {                            
     items.forEach(item => {
    // process each item             
 });
```

});

Frankly speaking I expected that if we use `let` for loop it means we create a closure for each iteration therefore I don't see any hidden problems there.

Comment: Is that snippet from the book, or from before ES6 was out? You are right that using `let` or `const` in the loop is enough to make the variable different per-loop. The issue described there only applies to `var`.

Comment: The "hidden problem" would  be starting many HTTP requests at the same time. If the list `items` has 200 things in it, that would be 200 concurrent HTTP requests. I think that the paragraph you quoted could be made more clear.

Comment: It's book RxJS in Action from Manning

Comment: @Pointy Maybe, but the suggested fix of ".forEach" to create a closure would have the same problem, so it makes me think that isn't the issue being described.

Comment: @loganfsmyth unfortunately there's nothing more about this paragraph

Comment: @Pointy Is that really a problem? Wouldn't a browser do a decent job of queuing the HTTP requests and not try to send them them all concurrently? The only issue I can think of is that if there are thousands of `items` some HTTP requests won't get sent for quite a while while they sit in the queue, but if you want to make that many HTTP requests, you can't avoid that anyway.

Comment: @Paulpro for just a few, probably not; I can't think of anything else that that paragraph might be describing however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, if the author's comment is on that exact code snippet, they were mistaken.

> Loops aren’t aware that there’s latency in those calls [...] you can improve matters by [...] using forEach()

That changes nothing, `forEach()` is equally unaware of async calls made inside its callback as a for loop is of async calls made in its body. `forEach()` will "always march ahead" the same way a for loop will.

With `let` you cannot encounter the issue that the author seems to be worried about, as each iteration of the loop has its own `item` just like when using `items.forEach( item => { ...` .

Even with `var` there is no issue with that code, since the variable `item` is not used inside the callback to the ajax request. You could produce the author's concern by using `var` and using `item` inside the callback, such as: `console.log( item.getId() );`.

Note: It is important to be aware that the callbacks will most likely run in a different (seemingly random) order than they were initiated in. If you aren't aware of that it can cause surprising bugs, but that also has nothing to do with using a loop vs. forEach.

Answer (score 1):

The authors of that book seem to have no clue. There is no problem of `for (let … of …)` that `.forEach(…)` would fix.

They talk about

> creating closures around your asynchronous functions, managed by using forEach() instead of the loop

but the closure is not created by the `forEach` callback function, the closure is the callback passed into the `ajax` function. It *closes* over the surrounding scope, and there is hardly any difference between the `for` block scope (when using `let` or `const`) and the function body scope (when using `forEach`).